# How to transform categorical column using one hot encoder in sklearn

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataframe with a categorical column and am trying to `one hot encode` it using `sklearn` using the below snippit

```
oneEncoder= OneHotEncoder()
features['COL2'] = features['COL2'].apply(lambda col :  oneEncoder.fit_transform(col))
```

but it keep throwing
`ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=1771. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`

I also tried

```
oneEncoder= OneHotEncoder() #initializing an object of class LabelEncoder
oneEncoder.fit_transform( features['COL2'])
```

but it throws 
`ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:`

Comment: You cannot assign back to `Col2` as the result of `OHE` transformation is a multidimensional one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
oneEncoder.fit_transform(df[["Col2"]]).todense()
```

Suppose we have:

```
features = pd.DataFrame({"Col2":["a","b","c"]})
```

Then:

```
oneEncoder= OneHotEncoder()
oneEncoder.fit_transform(features[["Col2"]]).todense()
matrix([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]])
```

If you're dealing with a `Series` object, you may wish to reshape it:

```
oneEncoder.fit_transform(features.Col2.values.reshape(-1,1)).todense()
matrix([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]])
```

Dropping `todense()` method will leave your transformation in a sparse matrix.

And finally, you may alway decode what the columns of your matrix mean by:

```
oneEncoder.categories_
[array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)]
```

Not surpisingly, they are your unique inputs ordered alphabetically.

Comment: I optend to use `oneEncoder.fit_transform(features.Col2.values.reshape(-1,1)).todense()` but when I try to print the values it prints the old categorical value not the OHE

Comment: You need to concat new values.

Answer (score 0):

you could do directly

```
categories = pd.get_dummies(features['COL2'])
```

otherwise you could pass a 2d array instead

```
oneEncoder.fit_transform( features[['COL2']].values)
```

Comment: I followed the 2nd approach ... but when I print the column value, it prints the categorical value, not the `OHE` representation